# Cannot fetch data from MSAccess in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I am trying to fetch data from a MS Access table. The query with which I am trying to fetch data is fetching results in MS Access but I cannot get any data in C#. Following is my code:

```
public DataTable GetData(string _strTableName, string _strSQL)
        {
            //Get db connection            
            string _strdbconn = GetDbConn();


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(_strTableName);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            //Open Access Connection
            OleDbConnection AccessConn = new OleDbConnection(_strdbconn);

            try
            {

                //Fetch Data
                AccessConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand AccessComm = new OleDbCommand(_strSQL, AccessConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter AccessDataAdptr = new OleDbDataAdapter(AccessComm);
                AccessDataAdptr.Fill(ds, _strTableName);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                AccessConn.Close();
                AccessConn.Dispose();
            }

            return ds.Tables[_strTableName];
        }
```

Following is the SQL that I am using:

```
SELECT CostCenterNumber FROM CostCenterDetails where CostCenterNumber like '100*';
```

What might be the cause that I am not getting any data at C# end?

Comment: Did you execute the query directly in access?

Comment: Is the CostCenterNumber field numeric or string ?

Comment: Side note: `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is *useless*.

Comment: Yes I ran it in access directly, it is returning 934 rows, I am catching the exception in DBContext, this function is in DAL layer and is a generic function used by other DBContexts, it is fetching data for other queries I dont know why this one is not working.

Comment: CostCenterNumber is Text field

Comment: Try to replace '100*' by '100%'. (standard LIKE clause uses the "%")

Comment: If i use % then the query is not fetching any result in access it self. Hence I used *. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ms Access uses "*" as a wildcard like. However, C# OleDb API still uses the "%", i.e. the ANSI wild card.